# error 500 for .htaccess error

Tags: .htaccess

I am running a LAMP server, and this .htaccess is giving me a 500 error. What this does is filter keywords and redirect to the respective domain names.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} xy|yz|xz
RewriteRule ^xyz.com

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ab|bc|ac
RewriteRule ^abc.net


<IfModule>
```

**Error Message from error.log**

```
/var/www/conf/.htaccess: <IfModule> directive requires additional arguments, referer: http://localhost/conf/rewrite.php
```

Why does it give me a 500 error, do I have to check if IfModule is installed, or has to be installed.

Thanks Jean

Comment: Guys there are over 14K Q tagged for linux, over 4.4K tagged fr .htaccess, so please do not ask me to move this to superuser.com.  A question is relevant if are tags and source to answer.

Comment: Take a peek into `error.log` to get a verbose error message

Comment: superuser? Who is suggesting Superuser? Are you hearing voices? ;)

Comment: @pekka not you in particular, got some living beings who say so

msg from error.log

/var/www/conf/.htaccess: <IfModule> directive requires additional arguments, referer: http://localhost/conf/rewrite.php

Answer (score 6):

You are missing a slash. The closing tag must be

```
</ifModule>
```

that also explains the error message: `<IfModule> directive requires additional arguments`

Answer (score 0):

You are using [**`RewriteRule`**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) with only one parameter :

```
RewriteRule ^abc.net
```

Judging from the manual, the syntax is :

```
RewriteRule Pattern Substitution [flags]
```

I would say you need to indicate the destination of your rewriting.

Comment: @martin could you tell me what is wrong.  The error msg is


/var/www/conf/.htaccess: <IfModule> directive requires additional arguments, referer: http://localhost/conf/rewrite.php

Comment: Humph, strange : it seems you have provided the required parameter to `IfModule`... still, did you try adding the necessary destination to `RewriteRule` ?

Comment: In `RewriteRule ^abc.net`, `^abc.com` is the Pattern ; but the is no `Substitution` defined, here -- and `RewriteRule`'s syntax expects a `Pattern`, and a `Substitution`.

Comment: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} xy|yz|xz is the condition

Comment: Still, the manual doesn't seem to indicate that `RewriteRule` only takes one parameter ; even when used with `RewriteCond`.

Comment: And where will I use a range of keywords for example abcdef.com I want keywords abc def ac alphabets to be redirected to abcdef.com

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a pattern in the requested URL to match, and a destination to redirect to. Try:

```
RewriteRule (.*) http://abc.net$1
```

Comment: and this RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} xy|yz|xz is the condition