# .htaccess <IfModule> Directive Causing Internal Error 500

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm a newbie to laravel. I'm getting an internal error 500 when I go to mydomain.com.

My error log says:

```
[Sun Nov 20 22:04:48.310309 2016] [core:alert] [pid 364784:tid 140380089542400] [client 141.101.105.69:27886] /public_html/public/.htaccess: <IfModule> directive requires additional arguments
```

I found this thread which sounds like my problem; Laravel blank white screen

But I'm on shared hosting and do not have SSH access. How can I execute this fix on shared hosting?

**Edit from comments:** My /public_html/public/.htaccess file is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    <IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Most of the times, it happens because of incorrect permission. Please ensure if you have set correct permission for the directory and sub-diretctories

Comment: HTTP 500 is a generic error message. Whenever you see it your first step should _always_ be to check your server logs .That should show more helpful error messages.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. The comments above have some good suggestions on where to start. When you've had a try at them, can you please edit your question and add all the information that you find (don't post it in comments because it's hard to follow and code formatting is dreadful). Generally it's a good idea for you to have had a go at solving this yourself, and to tell us what you've tried (and show us the results/error-messages) so that we don't repeat any effort you've gone to (and so you show that you have put in some effort) :)

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering my question, newbie mistake, I didn't check the error logs. It seems to be a problem with my .htaccess file, I've posted the exact message in my original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a blank IfModule directive in your .htaccess. You need to update it to state which module it is querying for the existence of. See:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#ifmodule

Or post your .htaccess for help.

For example, to define a block in your .htaccess that only applied if the php module is loaded on the server, you might use:

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
```

Alternatively, if it is the closing directive, then you are missing a forward slash and need to change it to:

```
</IfModule>
```

Ref: [error 500 for .htaccess error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597715/error-500-for-htaccess-error)
Ref: https://serverfault.com/questions/257986/error-500-for-htaccess-error

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this is my .htaccess file in my /public_html/.htaccess. http://pastebin.com/Ghq6dsKe The script I'm using has multiple .htaccess files, if you want me to upload them all please inform me. Thanks!

Comment: I think you are missing a slash on the closing directive, change the bottom one to </IfModule> or copy it back from pastebin which already fixed it for you :-)

Comment: Hello, thanks for your input. However, this didn't work; I wasn't missing a slash. Do you have any other suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Try removing the two IfModule directives completely and just leave the three lines they contain. Is that your whole .htaccess file?

Comment: I removed all the stuff in between the <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> and the </IfModule> (This is what I'm supposed to do right?) and it did change the site, however my site still isn't working. Right now, instead of an internal error 500, it shows me one of those "Index of /" pages and shows all my files.

Comment: No the other way round! Leave the stuff in between and just remove <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> and </IfModule>

Comment: Oh, sorry about that! Like I said, I'm a newbie, lol. I did that and nothing changed, still an error 500. Any other suggestions? Thanks for your help!

Comment: If it helps, I have multiple .htaccess files in my script and can upload the others if that would be any help.

Comment: My error log now says the same thing as before; <IfModule> directive requires additional arguments

Comment: You need to be sure you're uploading /public_html/public/.htaccess which is the one being complained about in the error log

Comment: Please consider upvoting any comments you feel have been helpful, and my answer if you feel it has been helpful. Once this is resolved, please accept the answer that solved your problem by ticking it. To upvote a comment use the little up arrow on the left of each comment. Welcome to Stack Overflow :)

Comment: Oh, ok, so I uploaded the wrong thing. Sorry about that! Thanks for bearing with me and my beginner questions, here is the actual file for /public_html/public/.htaccess: http://pastebin.com/EkrJWZP0

Comment: Also, all of your comments have been helpful, however I don't see an up arrow on the left of comments. Is it because my account is too new? I've upvoted your initial answer. :)

Comment: Great so on line four add a forward slash making it </IfModule>

Comment: To upvote, you may have to click on the comment before you see it. Or perhaps you can't do that yet as you're new. You can upvote my answer though I think, and hopefully accept it now too :)

Comment: Hello, unfortunately I added a forward slash on line 4 but I'm still getting the 500 error. It also returns the same error in my error log. Do you have any other suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: If it helps, before I added the forward slash, it gave me text on a page saying I had an error 500, but now it only gives me a white page.

Comment: It's fixed now. The white page is what is being loaded from your index file I guess. Try refreshing a few times and you will see the error doesn't get repeated in the log. It's just there from before.

Comment: Please accept my answer as it has fixed the problem you asked about. You can ask another question if the white page is confusing you.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I've accepted your answer. I still need to fix the white page though, I guess I'll be opening another question.

Comment: You could try viewing source to see what is behind the white page. If you ask a question you will need to put a lot of information for someone to be able to help you. Give all the detail you can. Good luck! Thanks for taking care of the admin and accepting my answer.